# Add column to track percent/rate of change

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table which captures backup file sizes and creation dates. It is my hope that I can track down which backup files are growing at a faster rate than others. How can I setup a query to add a column to track the percentage growth or rate of growth?

Example data:

```
Filename    CreationDate                Size
DB1         2017-06-19 13:00:28.450     96480
DB1         2017-06-20 13:00:36.627     97568
DB2         2017-06-18 22:00:00.800     19672
DB2         2017-06-19 22:00:00.370     19672
DB2         2017-06-20 22:00:00.913     19672
DB3         2017-06-18 22:00:04.520     17872840
DB3         2017-06-19 22:00:05.183     17873864
DB3         2017-06-20 22:00:06.400     17878984
```

Edit: I would like to have 2 separate new columns which track the percentage change. Column1 will be the percentage change since the most recent (i.e. change between yesterday and today). Column2 will be the percentage change cine the oldest file on record (i.e. change between today and the oldest date for the specific filename). Hope that helps. Also not sure why I got downvoted for this question.

Comment: The statement for altering the schema depends on your RDBMs implementation. Tag the correct one but it will be something similar to `alter table XXX add XXX decimal(x,y) null`

Comment: use a window function (lead/Lag) to look back/ahead at prior file size you can get a % change from previous size per file.

Comment: @igor I tagged TSQL which I thought would be sufficient to identify the RDBMS. I have updated the question with the SQL-Server tag.  This is also more involved than simply adding a column.  This is a calculated column based on values in the other columns.

Answer (score 0):

tSQL... assuming SQL server.  You have window functions available that can look ahead at the next record in the partition(filename) allowing you to do the percentages in a query.

```
SELECT td.fileName
     , td.creationdate
     , td.size
     , lag(td.size) over (partition by td.filename order by td.creationdate asc) / td.size as PercentChange
FROM TableData td
```

The "magic" is here: `lag(td.size) over (partition by td.filename order by td.creationdate asc)`

This basically says return the size of the record having the same filename as this one but a creationdate before the record being evaluated.

Using this we can get the prior value if one exists. and then do some basic math.  I wasn't sure how you wanted to do the % if it's New size / old or something else...  Note if size is an integer we may have integer math involved so you may have to cast size to a decimal value of sufficient size (if you need the decimals)

Comment: Size is of type float. When I run the query I get the wrong calculations. If the file size doesn't change it reports a 1 (I'm assuming 100%), whereas the other files are showing 99% or 101%. I would expect if the size to say the same, then the percentage change would be 0.